# What is the advantage of deploying source code with asp.net 5 applications?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, dnx

So, by default `dnu publish` packages your app with the source code of your application. You have the option of choosing not to do with and a command line argument (`no-source`).

I was wondering why the default option is with source code and what is advantage of it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Publishing with sources is mostly a development scenario. Since `dnu` is a dev tool, we've decided to make publish with sources the default.

Advantage: you can edit the files in any text editor directly on the server. Next time the server starts it picks up the changes. If you use Azure Websites, you can edit the code files directly in the browser.

Disadvantage: the server starts slower because it has to compile the sources.